# Pandas DataFrame: How to get a min value in a vectorized way?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
import numpy
import pandas

df1         = abs((pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(20, 8))*100).astype(int))
df1.columns = list('abcdefgh') 
df1.index   = pandas.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=20)
```

[image]

How would I create a new column that will give me the minimum value of the first half of the current row and the last 3 values in the previous row?

For example, the first five rows in the created column would be:

```
Nan 
12
4
14
21
```

Comment: Sorry what does `minimum value of the first half of the current row and the last 3 values in the previous row`  mean? please post sample desired output

Comment: The first 4 numbers in the current row and the last 3 numbers in the previous row, and get the minimum value from those 7 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. Basically, you need to first `shift` last three columns and then combine with the first 4 columns, and finally calculate the `min`.

```
import numpy
import pandas

# your data
# ===================================
numpy.random.seed(0)
df1         = abs((pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(20, 8))*100).astype(int))
df1.columns = list('abcdefgh') 
df1.index   = pandas.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=20)

# processing
# ===================================

df1['custom_min'] = pandas.concat([df1[df1.columns[:5]], df1[df1.columns[-3:]].shift(1)], axis=1).min(axis=1)

print(df1)

              a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h  custom_min
2014-01-01  176   40   97  224  186   97   95   15          40
2014-01-02   10   41   14  145   76   12   44   33          10
2014-01-03  149   20   31   85  255   65   86   74          12
2014-01-04  226  145    4   18  153  146   15   37           4
2014-01-05   88  198   34   15  123  120   38   30          15
2014-01-06  104  142  170  195   50   43  125   77          30
2014-01-07  161   21   89   38   51  118    2   42          21
2014-01-08    6   30   63   36   67   35   81  172           2
2014-01-09   17   40  163   46   90    5   72   12          17
2014-01-10  113  123   40   68   87   57   31    5           5
2014-01-11  116   90   46  153  148  189  117   17           5
2014-01-12  107  105   40  122   20   97   35   70          17
2014-01-13    1  178   12   40  188  134  127   96           1
2014-01-14  117  194   41   74  192  148  186   90          41
2014-01-15   86  191   26   80   94   15   61   92          26
2014-01-16   37  109   29  132   69   14   43  184          15
2014-01-17   67   40   76   53   67    3   63   67          14
2014-01-18   57   20   39  109  149   43   16   63           3
2014-01-19  238   94   91  111  131   46    6  171          16
2014-01-20   74   82    9   66  112  107  114   43           6
```